# Using boost::iterator_range; where is my data going out of scope?

Tags: c++, boost, scope

I get **invalid read / segmentation fault** errors using **boost::iterator_range**.
Where is my data going out of scope and how can I prevent that from happening?

Here is some code to reproduce the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/range.hpp>
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>
```

These are my types:

```
typedef double Value;
typedef std::vector<Value> vValue;
typedef boost::iterator_range<std::vector<Value>::iterator> rValue;
```

Utility function:

```
void print_range(const rValue &r) {
    for(rValue::difference_type i = 0; i < r.size(); ++i) std::cout << r[i] << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

This is an object that stores a cache of all data.

```
class MyDataObject { // This object stores ALL DATA.
private:
    vValue data;

public:
    void setData(vValue data) {
        this->data = data;
    }
    vValue &getData() {
        return data;
    }

};
```

Data segments are then created as a subset of all data using boost::iterator_range.

```
class DataSegment { // This object points to a subset of all data using boost::iterator_range
private:
    rValue data;

public:
    void setData(rValue data) {
        this->data = data;
    }
    rValue& getData() {
        return data;
    }
};
```

Actual database implementation:

```
class DB { // The database caches ALL DATA and then returns a subset using boost::iterator_range when asked for.
private:
    std::map<std::string, MyDataObject> cache;

public:
    DB() {
        //
    }

    MyDataObject loadIntoCache(std::string key) {
        vValue data = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

        MyDataObject obj;
        obj.setData(data);

        cache[key] = obj;
        return obj;
    }

    boost::shared_ptr<DataSegment> getMemoryEfficientSubset() {
        MyDataObject obj = loadIntoCache("bar"); // If bar is not in cache, load it.

        rValue data = obj.getData();

        boost::shared_ptr<DataSegment> segment(new DataSegment());
        rValue out = boost::make_iterator_range(data.begin() + 2, data.begin() + 7);
        segment->setData(out);

        return segment;
    }
};
```

Test code:

```
int main() {
    DB *db = new DB();

    boost::shared_ptr<DataSegment> segment = db->getMemoryEfficientSubset();
    print_range(segment->getData()); // ERROR: segfault within print_range. Valgrind says "Invalid read of size 8"

    delete db;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iterator range ultimately stored in `*segment` is associated with `data`, which is local to the call. Presumably you meant `loadIntoCache` to return a `MyDataObject&` (initialized from e.g. `cache[key] = obj`), which would remain valid as long as the cache is. Make also sure that `obj` is a reference to the result of the call to `loadIntoCache`, not a copy, and similarly for `data` and the result of the call `obj.getData()`.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem by using pointers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/range.hpp>
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>

typedef double Value;
typedef std::vector<Value> vValue;
typedef boost::iterator_range<std::vector<Value>::iterator> rValue;

void print_range(const rValue &r) {
    for(rValue::difference_type i = 0; i < r.size(); ++i) std::cout << r[i] << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

class MyDataObject { // This object stores ALL DATA.
private:
    vValue data;

public:
    void setData(vValue data) {
        this->data = data;
    }
    vValue& getData() {
        return data;
    }

};

class DataSegment { // This object points to a subset of all data using boost::iterator_range
private:
    rValue data;

public:
    void setData(rValue data) {
        this->data = data;
    }
    rValue& getData() {
        return data;
    }
};

class DB { // The database caches ALL DATA and then returns a subset using boost::iterator_range when asked for.
private:
    std::map<std::string, MyDataObject*> cache;

public:
    DB() {
        //
    }

    MyDataObject *loadIntoCache(std::string key) {
        vValue data = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

        MyDataObject *obj = new MyDataObject();
        obj->setData(data);

        cache[key] = obj;
        return obj;
    }

    boost::shared_ptr<DataSegment> getMemoryEfficientSubset() {
        MyDataObject *obj = loadIntoCache("bar"); // If bar is not in cache, load it.

        rValue data = obj->getData();

        boost::shared_ptr<DataSegment> segment(new DataSegment());
        rValue out = boost::make_iterator_range(data.begin() + 2, data.begin() + 7);
        segment->setData(out);

        return segment;
    }

    ~DB() {
        for(std::map<std::string, MyDataObject*>::iterator i = cache.begin(); i != cache.end(); ++i) delete i->second;
    }
};

int main() {
    DB *db = new DB();

    boost::shared_ptr<DataSegment> segment = db->getMemoryEfficientSubset();
    print_range(segment->getData()); // ERROR: segfault within print_range. Valgrind says "Invalid read of size 8"

    delete db;
    return 0;
}
```